# Effects of vector pushback on element address

Tags: c++, vector, memory-address, push-back

I have a vector of class objects. A function randomly choses two elements and return their addresses.

Now using these two elements, I want to generate two new objects of the same class and add them to the vector by using push_back.

Here is the address of the two parent elements:

No problem here. The first child object is then generated, and I use vector_pushback to add it to the end of the vector. The problem is, after the push_back command has been executed, it seems like the addresses of the parent objects change. Here is the state of debugger after push_back:

As you can see, the addresses obviously stay the same, but it seems like they point to garbage values after push_back. To my understanding, push_back adds an element at the end of the vector. Therefore I expect the address of the 2 elements to not change at all.

What's wrong?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

**TL;DR version:**

[An insertion operation can invalidate any pointers, references or iterators to elements of a `std::vector`.](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/vector/push_back)

**Full explanation:**

A `std::vector` has two useful metrics:

- [`size`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/vector/size), which is the number of elements stored.
- [`capacity`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/vector/capacity), which is the number of elements it's currently capable of storing.

`capacity >= size` at all times.

The `capacity` is the length of the internal dynamically-allocated array.<sup>*</sup>  When you insert an element, the `size` increments by 1.  But once it reaches `capacity`, a new, larger array must be allocated (hence increasing the `capacity`).  This requires all the elements to be copied across, and the originals to be deleted.  So all their addresses change.

---

<sub>* This is the typical internal implementation of a `std::vector`.</sub>

Comment: Wow, I wish there was a +2 button

Answer (score 2):

`push_back` can cause reallocation and moving of **all** elements in the vector, if the space that's currently assigned for element storage cannot contain the new element.